Same encryption algorithm in c# and java produces different output
I have C# code to encrypt password. I want to convert it to java. The converted java code produces different encrypted string than c#.
What can i do so that output is same for both java and c#.
Password: Hello World2
C# output: orc_Aup5rLQZ_vB5atFuqw2
Java output: orc_Aup5rLQZ_vB5atFuqw==
C# code
    using System;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Security.Cryptography;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Web;
        
        namespace Crypto.Client
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     Helper functions to encrypt and decrypt stuff
            /// </summary>
            public static class CryptoHelper
            {
                private static readonly byte[] Key =
                    {
                        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12,
                        0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
                    };
        
                private static readonly byte[] InitializationVector =
                    {
                        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
                        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
                    };
        
                //Encrypts the input string using a .net function.
                public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
                {
                    var rmCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (
                            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
                                memoryStream, rmCrypto.CreateEncryptor(Key, InitializationVector), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            using (var streamWiter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                            {
                                streamWiter.Write(plainText);
                            }
                        }
                        return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Java code:
public class CryptoHelper
{
    private static final byte[] Key =
    {
        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12,
        0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
    };

    private static final byte[] InitializationVector =
    {
        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
    };
    
    public static String Encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(InitializationVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream cryptoStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);
        cryptoStream.write(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        cryptoStream.close();
        
        byte[] encryptedBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

        
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
    }
}


apart from your question. The principle of your work is wrong, you should hash the passwords, not encrypt them

Do not used a fixed IV! That breaks the whole reason for the IV to exist. The IV must be different for different things which are encrypted with the same key.

Also, I'm not familiar with the Java APIs, but the fact that encVal is unused should be a bit of a red flag? Add to that the Java output is output is 2 bytes shorter, and it points towards a problem where you're omitting the final few bytes of the java output

@FedericoklezCulloca But those two base64 strings do contain different data. (And can two different Base64 strings encode the same value? Ignoring the presence/absence of trailing ='s, which isn't the issue here)

Although, the Java output is 16 bytes, which you'd expect from a full block, while the C# output is 17 bytes. I'm not sure where the final 0x0D is coming from though

You are simply using different encodings for the ciphertext. UrlTokenEncode() Base64url encodes, but also replaces the Base64 padding bytes (=) with a number that equals the number of padding bytes. This causes the difference.

Confirmed: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EsNa0w

@Topaco so in my java code i need replace padded bytes with number of padded bytes.

As mention in the comment by @topaco HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode replaces padded bytes(=) with a number that equals the number of padding bytes.
So I created a method to do this in java.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55426707/4498738
